# Playing a MIDI file using SoundFonts and NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to create a simple program that plays some notes using a preset from inside a Soundfont. To do this I am trying to use [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/). So far I have been able to successfully open a SoundFont, and get the names of all the instruments, presets, etc.:

```
NAudio.SoundFont.SoundFont sf = new NAudio.SoundFont.SoundFont("SoundFont.sf2");
MessageBox.Show(sf.Presets[0].Name); //Just looking at the first name
```

Now I want to be able to play sounds using those soundfonts, in the end from midi, but for now, just a note. I have played around with a few things, but not come up with anything so far.

Comment: Don't use your Google Search as a title for your questions.  Put your actual question in there.  Avoid including tags in your question titles.  Avoid please for help in your questions (especially pleas directed at specific users); we already know you're here to get help.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that @RobertHarvey. I referred to a user only because he was the creator.

Comment: If you have his email address, point him to this question, or place a polite comment below one of his posts.  He won't get notified if you put his name in your question.  Don't dismiss the other suggestions I gave you. :)

Answer (score 4):

NAudio can read information out of SoundFont files, but it does not include a SoundFont engine. For that you would need a good pitch shifting algorithm, some filters, and some voice management, as well as a sequencer if you wanted to play back MIDI files.

The closest I have come to building something like this is a demo I made for my [NAudio Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/audio-programming-naudio) course, in which I build a simple sampled piano based on some piano note recordings. If you are subscriber, you are free to use it. The technique I use is to load the sample into memory, connect a RawSourceWaveStream to it, convert it into a sample provider, and then pass it through a pitch shifter sample provider, based on the one I ported to C# for [this open source project](https://skypefx.codeplex.com/).